# Find location of process running in top command

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, process, top

When I run 'top' I see a process running named "watchdog" I read up on watchdog via the man page ala Google but I don't have that program installed. I've done a whereis and checked the /dev file to no avail. Can someone point me to finding where this process is coming from?

I'm running Ubuntu Server 14.04 with virtual box, virtual box headless & 'no machine' installed. Almost every other application or program I run is within a VM on the server & they're all powered down at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

The quick and easy (and classic) way to find the full command that was run is to do a grep through ps output:

```
[$]> ps aux | grep watchdog
```

However, I feel obliged to point out that this [isn't the most reliable way](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#ps_ax_.7C_grep_gedit), which would be

```
[$]> pgrep -fl watchdog
```

Comment: Thanks - I think I wasn't clear. I understand how to view the process itself. What I'm unclear on is now that I see the process is running how do I find out what application is associated with it and where the files related to it would be?

Comment: What do you mean by "application associated with it"?  If you want to know what the *parent* process is (that is, who launched it), you can do that with htop's tree mode, or `pstree`, or a few other methods.  What do you mean by "files related to it"?  If you want to see what files it currently has *open*, you can do that with `lsof`.

Comment: You said that you saw a process running but didn't think you had it installed - so if you look at the full path of the command (given by the things mentioned in my answer), that will show you where the executable is.